# Why inline element will return to its original position if I transform it when it be hovered?

Tags: css

I try to transform an element when it be hovered, like that:

```css
span{
  transition: transform 0.35s;
}
span:hover{
  transform: translateY(30px);
}
```

```html
<span>test</span>
```

On IE, it work well, but not on Chrome and Firefox.It will return to its original position.

I found if add `display:block` to span, it will fine(also has little problem with Firefox), but WHY? Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a **block-level** or **atomic inline-level element**, or whose display property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption [CSS21]
> - an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the attributes transform, ‘patternTransform‘ or gradientTransform [SVG11].

From the [w3 specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/).

So `inline-block` elements, `inline-table` elements, [replaced inline-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#replaced-elements) (think `img`, `video`, etc.) and possibly other [atomic inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13) are transformable inline-level elements.

If you make your span `display` either `block`, `inline-block` or `inline-table`, it will be considered a transformable element, otherwise it won't. What the browser does with non-transformable element is not specified.

```css
span{
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  display:inline-block;
}
span:hover{
  transform: translateY(30px);
}
```

```html
<span>test</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it returns to original position because it physically moves and the mouse is no longer hovering the element after the translation.

A couple ideas:

1) If you want the element to stay moved while the mouse is hovered but return when the mouse leaves, perhaps you could do a CSS3 Transition on `padding` instead of `translate`, that way the element content will move but the box in the DOM itself will stay to keep the `:hover` effect

2) If you want the element to stay in its place and not return after hovering, you will probably want to use Javascript to add a class to the element after hovering and style the class

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i hope to help. The problem with Firefox is that the *translateY* only applies in divs, therefore:

- Put your *span* within a div